# How to call new web usercontrol on click of a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button added to the aspx page and i want new web user control on click of that button.For eg. if a person has multiple address he can click the button and can add address1, address2, address3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Lbl_name" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Lbl_age" runat="server" Text="Age"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
<!-- Add the web user control in asp -->
<WebUserControl:WebTag id="MyControl" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Btn_add" runat="server" Text="Add" />
        <br /> 
        <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </td>
<br /><br  />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: What I think you want is Reponse.Redirect(WebAddress1) in your C# or vb code.  This will take you to the web: WebAddress1= www....com or within your site: WebAddress1 = ~/Default.aspx.

Comment: Btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     AddControl(1 + DataList1.Items.Count)
        protected void AddControl(int count)
          int b = DataList1.Items.Count;
           List<Control> list = new List<Control>();
               for (int i = 0; i < count; )
                Control c = new Control();
                   UserInfoBoxControl uc = LoadControl("UserInfoBoxControl.ascx") as UserInfoBoxControl;
                      uc.TotalTeam = "";
                   list.Add(c);                   i++;
             DataList1.DataSource = list;
           DataList1.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your functionality with JQuery as in this jsFiddle

**HTML**

```
 <div id="myDiv">
     <div id="item1">
         <input id="txt1" name="txt1" type="text"></input><input id="cmdAdd1" type="button" value="Add"></input>
     </div> </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var itemCount = 1;
$('#cmdAdd1').click(function(){addNewItem();});

function addNewItem(){
    var thisItem = itemCount;
    // Make last text box readonly
    $('#txt' + itemCount).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    // Change button to Remove button
    $('#cmdAdd' + itemCount).attr('value', 'Remove');
    $('#cmdAdd' + itemCount).unbind();
    $('#cmdAdd' + itemCount).click(function(){removeItem(thisItem );}); 

    // Add new line with text field and button
    itemCount++;
    var newItem = '<div id="item' + itemCount + '">'
    newItem += '<input id="txt' + itemCount + '" name="txt' + itemCount + '" type="text"></input>';
    newItem += '<input id="cmdAdd' + itemCount + '" type="button" value="Add"></input>';
    newItem += "</div>";

    $('#myDiv').append(newItem);
    $('#cmdAdd' + itemCount).click(function(){addNewItem();});    
}

function removeItem(i){
    $('#item' + i).remove();
}
```

Once your form has posted back to the server, you can iterate through the fields by walking the Form controls.

**C#**

```
int n=1;
while (Request["txt" + n] != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Request["txt" + n]);
    n++;
}
```